# Issues when using OR in @Query Spring data mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have following method in my repository:

`@Query(value = "{ '$or' : [ ?0 ]}") List<MyObject> findByObject(String lookupKeyValuePairs);`

I'm passing following String as input to this method.

String: `{ 'keyone': 'one','keytwo': 'one' },{ 'keyone': 'two','keytwo': 'two' }`

I expect the query to be `{ '$or' : [ { 'keyone': 'one','keytwo': 'one' },{ 'keyone': 'two','keytwo': 'two' } ]}` but spring is evaluating above query as

`org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - find using query: { "$or" : ["{ 'keyone': 'one','keytwo': 'one' },{ 'keyone': 'two','keytwo': 'two' }"] } fields: Document{{}} for class: MyClass in collection: MyCollection`

and throwing following exception:
`Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message '$or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects' on server`

It's dynamic parameters. The key value pairs are gonna change every time. That's why i'm passing the whole thing as a string.

Can someone help to point out where the issue is ?

Answer (score 0):

can you pass them as separate params?

```
@Query("{ '$or' : [ { 'keyone': ?0,'keytwo': ?1},{ 'keyone': ?2,'keytwo': ?3 } ]}") 
List<MyObject> findByObject(String param0, String param1, String param2, String param3);

repo.findByObject('one', 'one', 'two', 'two');
```

or

```
@Query("{ '$or' : [ { ?0: ?1, ?2: ?3},{ ?4: ?5, ?6: ?7 } ]}") 
List<MyObject> findByObject(String param0, String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4, String param5, String param6, String param7);

repo.findByObject('keyone', 'one', 'keytwo', 'one','keyone', 'two', 'keytwo', 'two');
```

or

---

option passing dynamic query params using criteria api

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.util.Pair;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyObjectService {

    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOps;

    public List<MyObject> findByObject(List<Pair<String, String>> orParams) {

        Criteria[] orCriteria = orParams.stream()
            .map(param -> Criteria.where(param.getFirst()).is(param.getSecond()))
            .toArray(Criteria[]::new);

        final List<MyObject> results = mongoOps.find(Query.where(new Criteria().orOperator(orCriteria)), MyObject.class);
        return results;

    }
}
```

---

```
List<MyObject> results = service.findByObject(List.of(
    Pair.of("keyone", "one"), 
    Pair.of("keytwo", "one"), 
    Pair.of("keyone", "two"), 
    Pair.of("keytwo", "two")
));
```

Comment: It's dynamic parameters. The key value pairs are gonna change every time. That's why i'm passing the whole thing as a string.

Comment: how about using criteria api, added above